# missing observations when replicating sample()

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to convince myself of the Central Limit Theorem as applies to proportions.

Consider the following generated data:

```
sales_team <- c("Amir", "Brian", "Claire", "Damian")

sample_rep <- replicate(1000, sample(sales_team, 10, replace = TRUE) %>%  
   table() %>% 
   prop.table())
```

`sample_rep` contains 1000 entries, each with the proportion of each name; however not all of the entries have four observations. In other words if "Damian" had been selected in the sample there is not a 0 for a zero proportion.

Thus the following generates an error.

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(sample_rep),nrow=length(sample_rep),byrow=TRUE))
```

R states:

> In matrix(unlist(sample_rep), nrow = length(sample_rep), byrow = TRUE) :
> data length [3803] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [1000]

Is there some way to create a dataframe of the results of the replicated sampling so as to generate a histogram of the proportions for each name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to make the input `sales_team` `factor`. This would return you 4 X 1000 matrix.

```
sales_team <- factor(c("Amir", "Brian", "Claire", "Damian"))
sample_rep <- replicate(1000, sample(sales_team, 10, replace = TRUE) %>% table() %>% prop.table())
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convince myself of the Central Limit Theorem as applies to proportions via the following:

```
sales_team <- factor(c("Amir", "Brian", "Claire", "Damian"))

sample_rep <- replicate(1000, sample(sales_team, 10, replace = TRUE) %>% table() %>% prop.table())
```

```
#matrix 4 X 1000, need 1000 X 4, so need to transpose. Use matrix() fun.
```

```
sample_data_matrix <- t(matrix(sample_rep,nrow=4,ncol=1000,dimnames = list(sales_team,NULL)))

sample_data<-data.frame(sample_data_matrix)
```

```
#generate histogram of Claire to show proportion of Claire approx. normal around 0.25
```

```
ggplot(sample_data,aes(Claire))+
geom_histogram(bins=10)
```